# How can I draw arrow on chart based on RSI cross below 50 and above 50?

Tags: mql5

I have tried using this code

```
#property indicator_chart_window    
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_width1  2
#property indicator_width2  2
#property indicator_color1 clrRed
#property indicator_color2 clrGreen

double upArrow[],downArrow[];
int draw;
int OnInit(){
   IndicatorSetString(INDICATOR_SHORTNAME,"Arrow");
   // Arrow
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_DRAW_TYPE,DRAW_ARROW,1);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_ARROW,233); // 233 159
   PlotIndexSetDouble(0,PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE,0.0);
   PlotIndexSetString(0,PLOT_LABEL,"Buy");
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,draw);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,upArrow);
   
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_DRAW_TYPE,DRAW_ARROW,1);
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_ARROW,234); // 234 233
   PlotIndexSetDouble(1,PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE,0.0);
   PlotIndexSetString(1,PLOT_LABEL,"Sell");
   PlotIndexSetInteger(1,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,draw);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,downArrow);

   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
   int limit = rates_total - prev_calculated;
   double RSIArray[];
   int rsi=iRSI(Symbol(),Period(),14,PRICE_CLOSE);
   ArraySetAsSeries(RSIArray,true);
   CopyBuffer(rsi,0,0,limit,RSIArray);
   
   MqlRates PriceInfo[];
   ArraySetAsSeries(PriceInfo,true);
   int PriceData = CopyRates(Symbol(),Period(),0,limit,PriceInfo);
   
   for(int i = limit - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
       double rsi_1 = RSIArray[i];
       double rsi_2 = RSIArray[i+1];
   
       if(rsi_2 < 50 && rsi_1 >= 50){          
          upArrow[i]=low[i+1]-10*Point();  
           Print("Cross above RSI 50 on candle: ", i, ", ", PriceInfo[i].close);
       }else if(rsi_2 > 50 && rsi_1 <= 50){
          downArrow[i]=high[i+1]+10*Point();
           Print("Cross below RSI 50 on candle: ", i, ", ", PriceInfo[i].close);
       }
   }
   return(rates_total);
}
```

I am not seeing any arrow on chart when I attach the indicator, I actually don't know what I am doing wrong. please help me out. I was able to see the print statement when the conditions are met, but the arrows are not drawn. I have also confirm that code to get RSI values is correct, same with the code to get the prices.